# Sql Server trace? Who is running it and how to stop it?

Tags: sql-server

Can you please help me out in finding who is running SQL Server Trace(profiler) on Server machine.?

It looks like, some people are running trace on live system on SQL DB, which make application super slow.

We need to find out who is running that or who ran that in the past? any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know... `sp_who` maybe?

Comment: Actually, the question is easily answered, which I will happily do once it is moved to the correct forum.

Comment: I am sorry but where do you want me to move this question?

Comment: @RBarryYoung shouldn't your answer migrate when the question is migrated as well?

Comment: @scsimon Yes, but 1) the OP might delete and repost their question, and 2) though I know at least one answer, there are folks there who can answer the question better than me.

Comment: Ah i see @RBarryYoung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will stop a trace

DBCC TRACEOFF (1222,-1)

Some traces are system traces.  For example trace 1222 turns on deadlock logging into the SQL Server error logs.  Be careful and find out what you are turning off before you do it.

Comment: This answer is simply not related to profiler trace in any way

Answer (score 5):

Run the SQL command below:

```
   select
          [Status] =
          case tr.[status]
                when 1 THEN 'Running'
                when 0 THEN 'Stopped'
          end
          ,[Default] =
                case tr.is_default
                      when 1 THEN 'System TRACE'
                      when 0 THEN 'User TRACE'
                end
           ,[login_name] = coalesce(se.login_name,se.login_name,'No reader spid')
          ,[Trace Path] = coalesce(tr.[Path],tr.[Path],'OLE DB Client Side Trace')
          from sys.traces tr
                left join sys.dm_exec_sessions se on tr.reader_spid = se.session_id
```

Source:- https://mssqlwiki.com/2010/04/26/how-to-find-all-the-profiler-traces-running-on-my-sql-server/

Comment: Sorry Nirjhar I am just askign above question to you as well. Just in case if you have any thought on this. is there any way I can stop my teammates running this trace during work hours? –

Comment: @user2040021 you would need to take away their admin rights.

Comment: @user2040021 You will have to alter the permissions of users

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft says:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187611(v=sql.110).aspx)

> By default, running SQL Server Profiler requires the same user permissions as the Transact-SQL stored procedures that are used to create traces. To run SQL Server Profiler, users must be granted the ALTER TRACE permission. For more information, see GRANT Server Permissions (Transact-SQL).

Essentially, you should be looking with anyone with admin rights on the box.  As far as who exactly that is, see who's got open connections with `sp_who` or `sp_who2`.

Comment: is there any way I can stop my teammates running this trace during work hours?

Comment: Yeah, remove their permissions. Either that or raise it with whoever needs to know to get it stopped.

Comment: Nirjhar has a response here on finding the offenders. Create a job that will close kill the associated SQL Server connections during work hours. Have it run once a minute.